# Is there an Overview document for the WCF RIA Services Beta for VS 2008 version?

Tags: silverlight, ria, wcf-ria-services

When I downloaded the Microsoft .NET RIA Services July 2009 Preview, I got a hundred-and-something page Overview document.  It looked like it had been revised from a previous release.  I've just downloaded the WCF RIA Services Beta for Visual Studio 2008 version but I can't find an updated Overview document.

Do you know is there is one?

Comment: have you checked out:   http://silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/   has a ton of articles, videos, and so on

Comment: I have.  There's a lot there but spread across loads of articles and videos.  I read a lot on the train and printing one 150 page doc is a lot easier than trawling web sites and printing individual pages (which isn't to say I haven't done that in the past) and I still can't take video with me.  At least, not in a usable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem not: [RIAServicesOverviewPreview.pdf for PDC09](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/145228/343659.aspx#343659).